# HTML Email causes Outlook 2007 to freeze on Windows Server 2003 x64 Terminal Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

I have a problem with Outlook 2007 on a Windows Server 2003 x64 Terminal Server.

Replying to or forwarding a HTML formatted email causes Outlook to freeze and crash as soon as Send is clicked. Emails that are plain text or Rich Text function normally. Another problem is that images won't display inside HTML emails after choosing to Download Pictures.

The problem only occurs in a RDP or ICA session. If I logon to a console session then images display correctly and HTML emails can be forwarded or replied to without crashing Outlook. The problem occurs regardless if the user has administrative rights or not.

All Office service packs and updates have been applied to the server. The server is running as a VM on a ESXI 5 host. Office Diagnostics doesn't show any problems. Re-installing or repairing Office 2007 has no effect. The same Office image and transform was used to install Office 2007 onto a physical Windows 2003 x64 server but it doesn't have this problem with Outlook.

Any ideas on what could be causing Outlook 2007 to crash or not display images in a RDP session?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a web browser from with the session? If not, that's probably your problem. I've run in to the same problem with authenticating proxies: Outlook can't complete the authentication process and chokes when it tries to download images.

Comment: Web browsing works fine in a RDP session. The problem occurs with and without proxy settings configured in IE.